# How can we implement drag and drop feature in html5

Tags: html

Hello everyone please suggest me how to implement drag and drop feature inside CANVAS of html5 using kineticJS it drag and dropped object should be able to display the id of the object.

Comment: http://html5.litten.com/how-to-drag-and-drop-on-an-html5-canvas/ is the link i went through but i've to display the id of the object that i dragged

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use canvas? This would be much easier simply using jQuery UI...

Answer (score 0):

May be this tutorials can help you!?

[Drag and Drop Events](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_drag_drop.htm)